# Error SQL Script - No crea todas las tablas completas

Tags: mysql, sql, script

Buenas Tardes!

Espero me puedan ayudar. 
Estoy creando una BD para un proyecto. El diseño lógico lo hice con `MySql Workbench` y genere el `Sql Script` para crear la base de datos. El asunto es que al ejecutar el `Script` en `MySql` solamente crea 6 tablas, de 17 tablas que tiene en total la BD.

Adjunto el `Sql Script`.
Y el print de pantalla de las tablas que crea.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
SET @OLD_UNIQUE_CHECKS=@@UNIQUE_CHECKS, UNIQUE_CHECKS=0;
SET @OLD_FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=@@FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS, FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0;
SET @OLD_SQL_MODE=@@SQL_MODE, SQL_MODE='TRADITIONAL,ALLOW_INVALID_DATES';

DROP SCHEMA IF EXISTS `mydb` ;
CREATE SCHEMA IF NOT EXISTS `mydb` DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci ;
USE `mydb` ;

-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `mydb`.`users`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE  TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `mydb`.`users` (
  `id_user` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT ,
  `nombre` VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL ,
  `apellido` VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL ,
  `ced_ident` INT NOT NULL ,
  `mail` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL ,
  `passw` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL ,
  `type_user` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'user' ,
  `location` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL ,
  `user_log_in` VARCHAR(45) NULL ,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id_user`) )
ENGINE = InnoDB
COMMENT = 'tabla de usuarios principales\n';

CREATE UNIQUE INDEX `id_user_UNIQUE` ON `mydb`.`users` (`id_user` ASC) ;


-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `mydb`.`nros_tlf`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE  TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `mydb`.`nros_tlf` (
  `id_nros_tlf` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT ,
  `nro_telefonico` INT NULL ,
  `users_id_user` INT NOT NULL ,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id_nros_tlf`, `users_id_user`) ,
  CONSTRAINT `fk_nros_tlf_users`
    FOREIGN KEY (`users_id_user` )
    REFERENCES `mydb`.`users` (`id_user` )
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
ENGINE = InnoDB;

CREATE INDEX `fk_nros_tlf_users_idx` ON `mydb`.`nros_tlf` (`users_id_user` ASC) ;

CREATE UNIQUE INDEX `id_nros_tlf_UNIQUE` ON `mydb`.`nros_tlf` (`id_nros_tlf` ASC) ;


-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `mydb`.`r_social`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE  TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `mydb`.`r_social` (
  `id_r_social` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT ,
  `user_owner` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL ,
  `name_r_social` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL ,
  `rif_r_social` VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL ,
  `location_r_social` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL ,
  `users_id_user` INT NOT NULL ,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id_r_social`, `users_id_user`) ,
  CONSTRAINT `fk_r_social_users1`
    FOREIGN KEY (`users_id_user` )
    REFERENCES `mydb`.`users` (`id_user` )
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
ENGINE = InnoDB;

CREATE INDEX `fk_r_social_users1_idx` ON `mydb`.`r_social` (`users_id_user` ASC) ;

CREATE UNIQUE INDEX `id_r_social_UNIQUE` ON `mydb`.`r_social` (`id_r_social` ASC) ;


-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `mydb`.`cesta`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE  TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `mydb`.`cesta` (
  `id_cesta` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT ,
  `ctidad` INT NOT NULL ,
  `status` VARCHAR(45) NULL ,
  `r_social_id_r_social` INT NOT NULL ,
  `r_social_users_id_user` INT NOT NULL ,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id_cesta`, `r_social_id_r_social`, `r_social_users_id_user`) ,
  CONSTRAINT `fk_cesta_r_social1`
    FOREIGN KEY (`r_social_id_r_social` , `r_social_users_id_user` )
    REFERENCES `mydb`.`r_social` (`id_r_social` , `users_id_user` )
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
ENGINE = InnoDB;

CREATE INDEX `fk_cesta_r_social1_idx` ON `mydb`.`cesta` (`r_social_id_r_social` ASC, `r_social_users_id_user` ASC) ;

CREATE UNIQUE INDEX `id_cesta_UNIQUE` ON `mydb`.`cesta` (`id_cesta` ASC) ;


-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `mydb`.`status`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE  TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `mydb`.`status` (
  `id_status` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT ,
  `descripcion` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL ,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id_status`) )
ENGINE = InnoDB;

CREATE INDEX `fk_status_cesta1_idx` ON `mydb`.`status` (`cesta_id_cesta` ASC, `cesta_r_social_id_r_social` ASC, `cesta_r_social_users_id_user` ASC) ;

CREATE UNIQUE INDEX `id_status_UNIQUE` ON `mydb`.`status` (`id_status` ASC) ;


-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `mydb`.`carrito`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE  TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `mydb`.`carrito` (
  `id_carrito` INT NOT NULL ,
  `items_add` INT NOT NULL ,
  `cantidad` INT NOT NULL ,
  `date_add` VARCHAR(45) NULL ,
  `r_social_id_r_social` INT NOT NULL ,
  `r_social_users_id_user` INT NOT NULL ,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id_carrito`, `r_social_id_r_social`, `r_social_users_id_user`) ,
  CONSTRAINT `fk_carrito_r_social1`
    FOREIGN KEY (`r_social_id_r_social` , `r_social_users_id_user` )
    REFERENCES `mydb`.`r_social` (`id_r_social` , `users_id_user` )
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
ENGINE = InnoDB;

CREATE INDEX `fk_carrito_r_social1_idx` ON `mydb`.`carrito` (`r_social_id_r_social` ASC, `r_social_users_id_user` ASC) ;

CREATE UNIQUE INDEX `id_carrito_UNIQUE` ON `mydb`.`carrito` (`id_carrito` ASC) ;


-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `mydb`.`status`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE  TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `mydb`.`status` (
  `id_status` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT ,
  `descripcion` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL ,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id_status`) )
ENGINE = InnoDB;


-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `mydb`.`status_has_carrito`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE  TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `mydb`.`status_has_carrito` (
  `status_id_status` INT NOT NULL ,
  `carrito_id_carrito` INT NOT NULL ,
  `carrito_r_social_id_r_social` INT NOT NULL ,
  `carrito_r_social_users_id_user` INT NOT NULL ,
  PRIMARY KEY (`status_id_status`, `carrito_id_carrito`, `carrito_r_social_id_r_social`, `carrito_r_social_users_id_user`) ,
  CONSTRAINT `fk_status_has_carrito_status1`
    FOREIGN KEY (`status_id_status` )
    REFERENCES `mydb`.`status` (`id_status` )
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT `fk_status_has_carrito_carrito1`
    FOREIGN KEY (`carrito_id_carrito` , `carrito_r_social_id_r_social` , `carrito_r_social_users_id_user` )
    REFERENCES `mydb`.`carrito` (`id_carrito` , `r_social_id_r_social` , `r_social_users_id_user` )
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
ENGINE = InnoDB;

CREATE INDEX `fk_status_has_carrito_carrito1_idx` ON `mydb`.`status_has_carrito` (`carrito_id_carrito` ASC, `carrito_r_social_id_r_social` ASC, `carrito_r_social_users_id_user` ASC) ;

CREATE INDEX `fk_status_has_carrito_status1_idx` ON `mydb`.`status_has_carrito` (`status_id_status` ASC) ;


-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `mydb`.`compras`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE  TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `mydb`.`compras` (
  `id_compras` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT ,
  `monto` INT NOT NULL ,
  `date` DATETIME NOT NULL ,
  `carrito_id_carrito` INT NOT NULL ,
  `carrito_r_social_id_r_social` INT NOT NULL ,
  `carrito_r_social_users_id_user` INT NOT NULL ,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id_compras`, `carrito_id_carrito`, `carrito_r_social_id_r_social`, `carrito_r_social_users_id_user`) ,
  CONSTRAINT `fk_compras_carrito1`
    FOREIGN KEY (`carrito_id_carrito` , `carrito_r_social_id_r_social` , `carrito_r_social_users_id_user` )
    REFERENCES `mydb`.`carrito` (`id_carrito` , `r_social_id_r_social` , `r_social_users_id_user` )
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
ENGINE = InnoDB;

CREATE INDEX `fk_compras_carrito1_idx` ON `mydb`.`compras` (`carrito_id_carrito` ASC, `carrito_r_social_id_r_social` ASC, `carrito_r_social_users_id_user` ASC) ;

CREATE UNIQUE INDEX `id_compras_UNIQUE` ON `mydb`.`compras` (`id_compras` ASC) ;


-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `mydb`.`posts`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE  TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `mydb`.`posts` (
  `id_posts` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT ,
  `date_creation` DATETIME NULL DEFAULT 0 ,
  `coments` INT NULL DEFAULT 0 ,
  `likes` INT NULL DEFAULT 0 ,
  `views` INT NULL DEFAULT 0 ,
  `users_id_user` INT NOT NULL ,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id_posts`, `users_id_user`) ,
  CONSTRAINT `fk_posts_users1`
    FOREIGN KEY (`users_id_user` )
    REFERENCES `mydb`.`users` (`id_user` )
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
ENGINE = InnoDB;

CREATE INDEX `fk_posts_users1_idx` ON `mydb`.`posts` (`users_id_user` ASC) ;

CREATE UNIQUE INDEX `id_posts_UNIQUE` ON `mydb`.`posts` (`id_posts` ASC) ;


-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `mydb`.`items`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE  TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `mydb`.`items` (
  `id_items` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT ,
  `description_item` VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL ,
  `type_item` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL ,
  `precio` INT NOT NULL ,
  `cant` INT NOT NULL ,
  `vistas` INT NOT NULL DEFAULT 0 ,
  `ventas` INT NOT NULL DEFAULT 0 ,
  `posts_id_posts` INT NOT NULL ,
  `posts_users_id_user` INT NOT NULL ,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id_items`, `posts_id_posts`, `posts_users_id_user`) ,
  CONSTRAINT `fk_items_posts1`
    FOREIGN KEY (`posts_id_posts` , `posts_users_id_user` )
    REFERENCES `mydb`.`posts` (`id_posts` , `users_id_user` )
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
ENGINE = InnoDB;

CREATE INDEX `fk_items_posts1_idx` ON `mydb`.`items` (`posts_id_posts` ASC, `posts_users_id_user` ASC) ;

CREATE UNIQUE INDEX `id_items_UNIQUE` ON `mydb`.`items` (`id_items` ASC) ;


-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `mydb`.`pagos`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE  TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `mydb`.`pagos` (
  `id_pagos` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT ,
  `description_f_pagos` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL ,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id_pagos`) )
ENGINE = InnoDB;

CREATE UNIQUE INDEX `id_pagos_UNIQUE` ON `mydb`.`pagos` (`id_pagos` ASC) ;


-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `mydb`.`pagos_has_items`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE  TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `mydb`.`pagos_has_items` (
  `pagos_id_pagos` INT NOT NULL ,
  `items_id_items` INT NOT NULL ,
  `items_posts_id_posts` INT NOT NULL ,
  `items_posts_users_id_user` INT NOT NULL ,
  PRIMARY KEY (`pagos_id_pagos`, `items_id_items`, `items_posts_id_posts`, `items_posts_users_id_user`) ,
  CONSTRAINT `fk_pagos_has_items_pagos1`
    FOREIGN KEY (`pagos_id_pagos` )
    REFERENCES `mydb`.`pagos` (`id_pagos` )
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT `fk_pagos_has_items_items1`
    FOREIGN KEY (`items_id_items` , `items_posts_id_posts` , `items_posts_users_id_user` )
    REFERENCES `mydb`.`items` (`id_items` , `posts_id_posts` , `posts_users_id_user` )
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
ENGINE = InnoDB;

CREATE INDEX `fk_pagos_has_items_items1_idx` ON `mydb`.`pagos_has_items` (`items_id_items` ASC, `items_posts_id_posts` ASC, `items_posts_users_id_user` ASC) ;

CREATE INDEX `fk_pagos_has_items_pagos1_idx` ON `mydb`.`pagos_has_items` (`pagos_id_pagos` ASC) ;


-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `mydb`.`img`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE  TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `mydb`.`img` (
  `id_img` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT ,
  `name` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL ,
  `address` VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL ,
  `ext` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL ,
  `items_id_items` INT NOT NULL ,
  `items_posts_id_posts` INT NOT NULL ,
  `items_posts_users_id_user` INT NOT NULL ,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id_img`, `items_id_items`, `items_posts_id_posts`, `items_posts_users_id_user`) ,
  CONSTRAINT `fk_img_items1`
    FOREIGN KEY (`items_id_items` , `items_posts_id_posts` , `items_posts_users_id_user` )
    REFERENCES `mydb`.`items` (`id_items` , `posts_id_posts` , `posts_users_id_user` )
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
ENGINE = InnoDB;

CREATE INDEX `fk_img_items1_idx` ON `mydb`.`img` (`items_id_items` ASC, `items_posts_id_posts` ASC, `items_posts_users_id_user` ASC) ;

CREATE UNIQUE INDEX `id_img_UNIQUE` ON `mydb`.`img` (`id_img` ASC) ;


-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `mydb`.`ventas`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE  TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `mydb`.`ventas` (
  `id_ventas` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT ,
  `monto` INT NOT NULL ,
  `fecha_comp` DATETIME NOT NULL ,
  `id_carrito` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL ,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id_ventas`) )
ENGINE = InnoDB;

CREATE UNIQUE INDEX `id_ventas_UNIQUE` ON `mydb`.`ventas` (`id_ventas` ASC) ;


-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `mydb`.`items_has_ventas`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE  TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `mydb`.`items_has_ventas` (
  `items_id_items` INT NOT NULL ,
  `items_posts_id_posts` INT NOT NULL ,
  `items_posts_users_id_user` INT NOT NULL ,
  `ventas_id_ventas` INT NOT NULL ,
  PRIMARY KEY (`items_id_items`, `items_posts_id_posts`, `items_posts_users_id_user`, `ventas_id_ventas`) ,
  CONSTRAINT `fk_items_has_ventas_items1`
    FOREIGN KEY (`items_id_items` , `items_posts_id_posts` , `items_posts_users_id_user` )
    REFERENCES `mydb`.`items` (`id_items` , `posts_id_posts` , `posts_users_id_user` )
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT `fk_items_has_ventas_ventas1`
    FOREIGN KEY (`ventas_id_ventas` )
    REFERENCES `mydb`.`ventas` (`id_ventas` )
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
ENGINE = InnoDB;

CREATE INDEX `fk_items_has_ventas_ventas1_idx` ON `mydb`.`items_has_ventas` (`ventas_id_ventas` ASC) ;

CREATE INDEX `fk_items_has_ventas_items1_idx` ON `mydb`.`items_has_ventas` (`items_id_items` ASC, `items_posts_id_posts` ASC, `items_posts_users_id_user` ASC) ;


-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `mydb`.`comentarios`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE  TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `mydb`.`comentarios` (
  `id_comentarios` INT NOT NULL ,
  `fecha` DATETIME NOT NULL ,
  `coments` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL ,
  `users_id_user` INT NOT NULL ,
  `posts_id_posts` INT NOT NULL ,
  `posts_users_id_user` INT NOT NULL ,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id_comentarios`, `users_id_user`, `posts_id_posts`, `posts_users_id_user`) ,
  CONSTRAINT `fk_comentarios_users1`
    FOREIGN KEY (`users_id_user` )
    REFERENCES `mydb`.`users` (`id_user` )
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT `fk_comentarios_posts1`
    FOREIGN KEY (`posts_id_posts` , `posts_users_id_user` )
    REFERENCES `mydb`.`posts` (`id_posts` , `users_id_user` )
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
ENGINE = InnoDB;

CREATE INDEX `fk_comentarios_users1_idx` ON `mydb`.`comentarios` (`users_id_user` ASC) ;

CREATE INDEX `fk_comentarios_posts1_idx` ON `mydb`.`comentarios` (`posts_id_posts` ASC, `posts_users_id_user` ASC) ;

CREATE UNIQUE INDEX `id_comentarios_UNIQUE` ON `mydb`.`comentarios` (`id_comentarios` ASC) ;

USE `mydb` ;

CREATE USER 'eleazar_super_admin' IDENTIFIED BY '20616897';

GRANT ALL ON `mydb`.* TO 'eleazar_super_admin';

SET SQL_MODE=@OLD_SQL_MODE;
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=@OLD_FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS;
SET UNIQUE_CHECKS=@OLD_UNIQUE_CHECKS;
```

Comment: Es muchísimo código en tu pregunta, recomiendo anexes tu script en algún servidor externo...

Comment: Lo siento, gracias por el comentario, estoy nuevo en esto de stackoverflow, en la practica corregiré estas malas practicas... Como subo este script a alguna servidor externo donde lo puedan consultar?

Answer (score 0):

El error que te muestra en la imagen es que estas intentando crear un índice en una tabla con unos campos que no existen.

La tabla en cuestión es ésta:

```
-- Table `mydb.status`

CREATE  TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `mydb`.`status` (
  `id_status` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT ,
  `descripcion` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL ,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id_status`) )
ENGINE = InnoDB;

CREATE INDEX `fk_status_cesta1_idx` ON `mydb`.`status` (`cesta_id_cesta` ASC, `cesta_r_social_id_r_social` ASC, `cesta_r_social_users_id_user` ASC) ;

CREATE UNIQUE INDEX `id_status_UNIQUE` ON `mydb`.`status` (`id_status` ASC) ;
```

El índice `fk_status_cesta1_idx` le estas pasando unos campos llamados `cesta_id_cesta`, `cesta_r_social_id_r_social` y `cesta_r_social_users_id_user` que no existen en esta tabla.

Ese índice parece que no va en esta tabla.

Comment: Entonces, sugieres que elimine esa linea de codigo? necesito que la tabla cesta haga referencia a 1 status.

Comment: Pero en el Índice que te estoy marcando: `CREATE INDEX fk_status_cesta1_idx ON mydb.status (cesta_id_cesta ASC, cesta_r_social_id_r_social ASC, cesta_r_social_users_id_user ASC) ;` le estas indicando que te cree un índice de la tabla `status` con unas columnas que no existen en esta tabla. Además la creación de la tabla `status` la tienes repetida en 2 sitios en el código que nos has proporcionado.